# Role of precedence in expression evaluation in C

Tags: c, expression, operator-precedence

If y is of integer type, then the expressions:

```
3*(y-8)/9
```

and

```
(y-8)/9*3
```

Will yield different result always or is it possible for them to yield same result?

What does it depend on?

Explanation with an example will be helpful.

Comment: What did you find when you ran the code?

Comment: You could just sweep `y` from 0 to, say, 100, and see the result.

Comment: What does your C book tell you?

Comment: The differences you'll see will be significantly impacted by integer-division if `y` is an integral type. It would be advantageous on your part to test it yourself with different values (in particular values where `(y-8)` is vs. is-not a multiple of `9` and `3`).

Comment: C compilers that are written *by the book* (following stated rules of precedence and associativity) should produce consistent results (barring differences in data type precision, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May yield different or same result, it is depend on 'y' value. The operations will be carried from left to right.
Ex: for y=11:
3*(y-8)/9: 1 (y-8)/9*3: 0

for y = 10
3*(y-8)/9: 0 (y-8)/9*3: 0